# CSS Flexbox not working for navigation (mobile screen)

Tags: css, flexbox

First off I am very new to CSS and following an online course.

I am trying to create a navigation bar that changes from row to column when going into mobile. I am using flexbox and @media queries for that however, it seems like my code does not make any change to the navigation direction when going to mobile. Please help! ]

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    justify-content: flex-end;

   

}


 .box {
    width: 90px;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;

}

.box-four {
    width: 100px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

   .container {
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-grow: 2rem;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-basis: 10%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML as well so I can properly test?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nada! :) It's best practice to provide a reproducible example which, for CSS, usually includes some HTML - doesn't have to be everything but enough that people can see the issue. For this question the issue seems obvious enough to me that I have provided an answer. If this answer doesn't solve the problem then please edit your question to include some HTML to reproduce the issue as you experience it.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! You are the best! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say exactly what problems you are having without seeing some example HTML to work with but at first glance it seems you should be using `flex-direction:column` for your mobile view.

Note well: What is in the media query is your mobile styles in this case. You can tell because you have specified `max-width` which means that it will apply to all screen sizes below the width provided (600px).

See the below as an example which incorporates your provided CSS with some basic HTML I made. (Resize the browser window to test).

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
}


 .box {
    width: 90px;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-four {
    width: 100px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

   .container {
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-grow: 2rem;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-basis: 10%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">Entry 1</div>
   <div class="box">Entry 2</div>
   <div class="box">Entry 3</div>
   <div class="box">Entry 4</div>
</div>
```

You can also read more about `flex-direction` at the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! You are the best! It worked.